# representations into $\mathfrak{sl}(n,\mathbb{C})$

Tags: reference-request, representation-theory

in Borel/Ji "Compactification of symmetric and locally symmetric spaces" the standard Satake compactification is constructed and general Satake compactifications are realized via an embedding into the standard compactification.

This embedding comes from a representation of $G \to PSL(n,\mathcal{C})$ and those correspond bijectively to representations $\mathfrak{g}\to \mathfrak{sl}(n,\mathbb{C})$. The latter are classified by highest weights.

I am looking for a reference where representations into $\mathfrak{sl}(n,\mathbb{C})$ are treated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For perfect Lie algebras $\mathfrak{g}$, i.e., satisfying $[\mathfrak{g},\mathfrak{g}]= \mathfrak{g}$, every linear representation $\phi\colon \mathfrak{g}\rightarrow \mathfrak{gl}_n(K)$ satisfies $\phi(\mathfrak{g})=\phi([\mathfrak{g},\mathfrak{g}])=[\phi(\mathfrak{g}),\phi(\mathfrak{g})]\subseteq [\mathfrak{gl}_n(K),\mathfrak{gl}_n(K)]=\mathfrak{sl}_n(K)$. In this sense, every reference on representation theory of Lie algebras is fine (e.g., the book by Fulton and Harris).

Comment: thanks. they assume semisimplicity.